# How to run and install Protractor E2E tests in Docker container for Laravel?

Tags: php, angularjs, laravel, docker, protractor

I have my **LAravel AngularJS application developed in [dockervel](http://www.spiralout.eu/2015/12/dockervel-laravel-development.html) .**
I have to **test AngularJS with e2e test in Protractor and after it I have to deliver the application including e2e tests.**

In this dockervel I have

**Containers included**

```
Nginx 1.8.0 & PHP 5.6 running in Alpine
MariaDB 5.5 running in Alpine
Redis running in Alpine
Composer PHP running in Alpine.
Artisan running in Debian (alpine is missing some PHP packages)
NodeJS with gulp, grunt and bower -g installed in official node:4.2.2-slim base image
Volumes mounted as containers
```

Aliases in dockervel:

```
alias dbuild='docker-compose build'
alias dup='docker-compose up -d'
alias dstop='docker-compose stop'
alias drun='docker-compose run -d --service-ports nginx'
alias dcomposer='docker-compose run composer'
alias dcomposer-create='docker-compose run composer create-project laravel/laravel /var/www --prefer-dist'
alias dpermit='chmod -R 777 www'
alias dartisan='docker-compose run artisan'
alias dnodejs='docker-compose run nodejs'
alias dgulp='docker-compose run nodejs gulp'
alias dgulp-watch='docker-compose run -d nodejs gulp watch'
alias dps='docker ps'
alias dpsa='docker ps -a'
alias dstats='docker stats $(docker ps -q)'
alias dkill='docker stop $(docker ps -q)'
alias drm='docker rm $(docker ps -a -q)'
alias dunit='docker-compose run  php php /var/www/html/vendor/bin/phpunit'
```

**Is there any way I could install and set up PRotractor to run inside his environment?**

Comment: you might wanna check this website- https://hub.docker.com/r/webnicer/protractor-headless/

Comment: Hm ,the problem is when i use this docker image the  browser doesn't open to show the action. Only in console I can see the test is passed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes it is headless, if you want to run your scripts with browser open. you just have to ignore the `protractor.sh` file and give the `protractor conf.js` command directly in the console.
It would launch your browser as usual!